# system() without shell

Tags: vimscript, shell

Is there a way to execute a host OS command directly, without spawning a shell that in turn runs the command? Preferably passing an argument list, in `execvp()` style? For example

```
" hypothetical
let finfo = systemexecvp('stat', fname)
```

Of course these days one has to add the disclaimer that this is **not about interpolating** variables in a shell command, **not about the `stat`** command or its portability, not about getting filesystem information etc.

Comment: Why do you need this? You could use `job_start()`. Of course you will have to take care of redirecting and all that stuff yourself then and getting the result back.

Comment: Yes, it is job_start(), with all the documented caveats of course! As to why -- It just seems wasteful, other languages have exec()'s. Plus the $SHELL setting itself seems problematic (is it sh? the top-heavy bash? maybe fish? I actually have /bin/sh my Unix shell, but it immediately executes fish if present).

Comment: It's whatever shell you configure with `:set shell` and related options.

Comment: I know, but when writing a plugin... And I've thought about setting the desired command "temporarily" as a shell, but that would still leave an unwanted `-c` argument, plus a single extra argument to pass to the command. Anyway, it's `job_start()`.

Comment: Honestly, that sounds like pre-mature optimizing. I would rather concentrate or actual problems

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I was pretty sure the premature optimization thing would pop up eventually. I sometimes wonder what the totality of the "not worth optimizing" decisions (which often disguise lazy implementations, bad designs, leaky abstractions etc) costs in terms of battery life (or energy usage).

Comment: Perhaps `term_start`, also

Comment: Please do not edit answers in to questions. Post an answer instead if you have a solution.

Comment: Hm... It didn't look like @ChristianBrabandt was going to add an answer, and I was about to move on from this question; so lest I forget, for the benefit of future readers... But whatever

Comment: I'll write an answer

Comment: @usretc it's all resolved now, so this is just FYI: self-answering is much preferred over editing the answer into your question. The problem is not *what* but *where*. I don't think anybody would have objected to an answer containing the exact same sentences.

Comment: OK. At the time I thought Christian *might* at some point add an answer (which he did), or someone else might copy the answer from the comments etc. Anyway, this is meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`system()`, as well as `:!cmd` always involves a shell. This can be verified by setting verbose mode `:set verbose=5` and then running a command:

```
let a=system('true')
Calling shell to execute: "(true)>/tmp/vhEpKqI/0 2>&1"
!true
Calling shell to execute: "true"
```

Typically Vim will use the users shell (`$SHELL`). But you can influence what shell to use and various other parameters. See the [help for an extensive list of options that influence the behaviour of the shell](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/c35fc03dbd47582b256776fb11f11d8ceb24f8f0/runtime/doc/options.txt#L6971-L7190).

If you want to bypass any shell and want to execute a command directly, you can use the channel feature together with the [job_start() function](https://vimhelp.org/channel.txt.html#job_start%28%29). Note this is Vim specific, but I am sure Neovim has something similar.

Note, bypassing a shell means you will have to take care of redirection, buffering, pty-options, and much more options. See the extensive help at [:h job-options](https://vimhelp.org/channel.txt.html#job-options).

And finally, if you want to run a command in the builtin terminal, without a shell, you can use the [term_start() function](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#term_start%28%29).

Comment: Regarding the shell-related options: it's not clear how they might be manipulated safely in a plugin (running on someone else's machine). I suppose one can use `setlocal` and then restore them, probably in a `try .. finally` block. But shell commands can be invoked outside of a buffer context (e.g. during startup)... Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

I would do:

```
let finfo=system(printf('stat "%s"', fname))
```

Comment: I would read the text of the question, though, as `system()` DOES spawn a shell. Better add more text to the disclaimer... Oh, and that would probably be `system('stat' .. shellescape(fname))`

Comment: How do you determine that a shell is spawn? In my tests I only have child process that is triggered.

Comment: `let x = system('/bin/sleep 100')` and then ps shows a nice sh/bash/whatever `-c (sleep 100)>/tmp/vRJ44z1/1 2>&1`. And don't tell me to use `system('exec /bin/sleep 100')` as that STILL spawns a shell, just one that immediately executes the command

Comment: You are right. I have analyzed further and indeed a shell is spawn. On Windows it is even two shells that are spawn :-|

Comment: it's actually logical that "someone" has to split the command around whitespaces; that someone is not vim, but the spawned shell. A lot of languages have `execv` commands, to complement their `system()` commands, which in turn rely on the execv* syscalls (with or without a fork())

Comment: Can you tell us why you don't want a shell? Would the solution going through the embedded python process a solution for you?

Comment: this is of course always calls a shell, as can be seen by :set verbose=5 or so